# SMTP Email Server Hosting on Google Cloud - Socket Error 10060

Tags: email, networking, google-cloud-platform, smtp, mail-server

I heard that port 25 is blocked on GCP, but I changed inbound and outbound ports for the SMTP server to 2525 which should be fine theoretically. I didn't know that when I registered.

When I'm trying to send emails using MDaemon Mail Server I'm getting Socket Error 10060.

What should be issue?

I opened all the needed ports on GCP firewall and Windows firewall is disabled.

Tried both Windows Server 2016 and 2019

```
Fri 2020-12-11 17:23:03.722: ----------
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: REMOTE message: pd3501000000001.msg
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: *  Session 00000014; child 0001
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: *  From: [censored]
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: *  To: ins-pn02qrxe@isnotspam.com
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: *  Subject: testing
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: *  Message-ID: <WC20201211165159.320001@[censored]>
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.719: *  Size: 2133; <c:\mdaemon\queues\remote\pd3501000000001.msg>
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.740: Resolving MX record for isnotspam.com (DNS Server: 10.172.0.1)...
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.753: *  P=010 S=000 D=isnotspam.com TTL=(59) MX=[isnotspam.com]
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.753: Attempting SMTP connection to isnotspam.com
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.753: Resolving A record for isnotspam.com (DNS Server: 10.172.0.1)...
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.757: *  D=isnotspam.com TTL=(59) A=[74.208.156.227]
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.757: Attempting SMTP connection to 74.208.156.227:2525
Fri 2020-12-11 17:27:42.757: Waiting for socket connection...
Fri 2020-12-11 17:28:03.761: *  Socket error 10060 - The connection timed out.
Fri 2020-12-11 17:28:03.761: *  This message is 35 minutes old; it has 25 minutes left in this queue
Fri 2020-12-11 17:28:03.762: SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out: 0/0)
```

**Thank you in advance for any kind of help!**

Comment: Did you followed this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use)

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using port 2525 for the SMTP output instead of 25. So I think that way it shouldn't cause any problem?

Comment: "If you want to use your own email server on a custom port, use the documentation specific to your email service to configure a custom email port."

I just did that and set up a custom port, 2525

Comment: Contrary to what you are reading, email is still sent email server -> email server over port 25. Ports 2525, 587, etc are for your own internal servers to listen on for your own clients to connect on. Once you want your email to leave your server to the Internet, it goes out on port 25. Port 25 is often blocked to prevent spam servers.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hmmm... So there is no way to change that?

Comment: If you could the spammers would also.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you should be able to use any port for any service My recommendation is to use ports 465 or 587, since they were designed to SMTP. And follow the guidance shared by Mahboob.

Or also, you can review the following [guidance](https://blog.cyberpanel.net/2018/05/30/setup-external-smtp-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp/) about use port 2525.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's not working even with port 587, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Attempting SMTP connection to 74.208.156.227:587
Waiting for socket connection...
Socket error 10060 - The connection timed out.

Comment: Would it be possible that my issue is not port related?

Comment: 22/tcp, 80/tcp ports are open on 74.208.156.227, I think you need to open 2525 port

Comment: 74.208.156.227 is the recipient's SMTP server at isnotspam.com, where I'm trying to send the email. All my ports are open, I checked it at least 100 times.